# Springboot posgresql reposity bean can't be autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I have simple Sprinngboot app where actual database is PostgreSQL.

My model:-

```
@Table("carrier")
@Entity
public class MyCarrier { 
@Id
@Column("id")
private UUID id;
    @Size(
            max = 100
    )
    @Column("carrier_name")
    private String carrierName;
    @Size(
            max = 3
    )
    @Column("smdg_code")
    private String smdgCode;
    @Size(
            max = 4
    )
    @Column("nmfta_code")
    private String nmftaCode;

    public MyCarrier() {
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getCarrierName() {
        return this.carrierName;
    }

    public String getSmdgCode() {
        return this.smdgCode;
    }

    public String getNmftaCode() {
        return this.nmftaCode;
    }

    public void setId(final UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setCarrierName(final String carrierName) {
        this.carrierName = carrierName;
    }

    public void setSmdgCode(final String smdgCode) {
        this.smdgCode = smdgCode;
    }

    public void setNmftaCode(final String nmftaCode) {
        this.nmftaCode = nmftaCode;
    }


    protected boolean canEqual(final Object other) {
        return other instanceof Carrier;
    }
}
```

Repository:-

```
@Repository
public interface MyCarrierRepository extends JpaRepository<MyCarrier, Long> {
}
```

Controller:-

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/upload")
public class ReactiveUploadResource {
    Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReactiveUploadResource.class);


    private final SqlRequestHandler sqlRequestHandler;

    @Autowired
    private  MyCarrierRepository myCarrierRepository;

    public ReactiveUploadResource(SqlRequestHandler sqlRequestHandler) {
        this.sqlRequestHandler = sqlRequestHandler;
    }
}
```

I got this error:-

Description:

Field myCarrierRepository in com.consumer.controller.ReactiveUploadResource required a bean of type 'com.consumer.repository.MyCarrierRepository' that could not be found.

What is missing? Why Springboot doesn't find this repository?

Comment: What are the packages of your repository interface, rest controller and class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`? And what attributes does the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation have?

Comment: Usually SpringBoot scans and includes all classes from packages at the same level as Application class and nested packages. I assume  `com.consumer.repository` is in parallel hierarchy. You have to tell SpringBoot to scan this package on start

Comment: MyCarrier entity primary key is of type UUID and in MyCarrierRepository you are using Long as ID.

Comment: As a general practice, you should include complete error log in your post than just first line. The root cause is at the end of the stack trace most of the times.

Comment: @ankit do u suggest I change MyCarrierRepository as UUID?

Comment: Maybe try to remove annotation @Table("carrier") from your model class MyCarrier..

Comment: @MasiBoo Yes. You have to use UUID as ID in MyCarrierRepository otherwise you will get errors when you try to use jpa methods such as findById(id) etc.

Comment: Sorry even after change to UUID or mention the @ComponentScan with correct basePackages. It doen't work.

Comment: Btw, there is another question should be simpler. Could pls check and give some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72572542/how-to-request-string-param-together-with-fluxpart-in-reactive-spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the repository inside the package at the same level as Application class  the packages to allow Spring boot to scan it